# database location in IDE

Tags: java, swing, derby

1- In Netbeans , this JDBC_URL works fine (using stand alone embedded Derby ):-

someApp (this is the directory)

```
|
src
    |
dataBasePackage.myDB
mainPackage
    |
    MainClass.java
```

JDBC_URL= “jdbc:derby:src/dataBasePackage/myDB”;

2- A folder on local machine  name : “appFolder” contains following :
[appFolder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvQlQ.png)

the .exe works fine and app starts...BUT user can’t connect to myDB ...which means JDBC_URL is wrong.

my question: When I want repackage the someApp to get a someApp.jar, I have to change the JDBC_URL to match the “appFolder” ; I tried multiple combinations,none worked !!

P.S: 
setting myDB on “file system” like  JDBC_URL=” jdbc:derby:myDB “ ...also not work though with different arrangement .

Comment: Don't ever reference `src` in your code, it won't exist after the program is packaged and released.  Unless you're intending to have a readonly database, you shouldn't be storing it in the `src` anyway. Your best bet is to store the database in a well known place, like  `{user.home}/Library/Application Support/{application name}` on Mac or `{user.home}/AppData/Local/{application name}` on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control the location of your database folder via your JDBC Connection URL, and via the specification of the Derby "system home".

Both these concepts are clearly explained in the Derby documentation. To read about that, start here: https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/devguide/cdevdvlp34964.html

The location can be specified in a relative or absolute fashion.

If you give an absolute database name in the Connection URL, the database is located at the name you specify. Since it is absolute, it doesn't depend on the Derby system home.

If you give a relative database name in the Connection URL, the database is located relative to Derby's system home: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper32066.html

Comment: @Bryan...Thanks ..your references streamlined my understanding to few missing concepts I had.;;; yet I like to know the distinctive differences in usage of derby.system.home & the String JDBC_URL  !